# Using Apache jmeter for MySQL through SSH

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jmeter

We have a web application hosted on Amazon Web services. We are using MySQL instance on EC2.

I want to stress test a DB on EC2 running MySQL. To connect to it one needs to use SSH. I can connect to it through putty. But I don't have any idea on how to use jmeter to run queries on this DB.

How can I connect to MySQL instance through SSH inside jmeter test plan?

I have tried jmeter-ssh sampler, but it only runs SSH commands over SSH. Not useful in my case, I guess.

Comment: You can install jmeter directly on the DB machine

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine you could do this through an ssh tunnel. There's a short tutorial for running jmeter through an ssh tunnel here:

http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2012/02/16/how-to-run-jmeter-over-ssh-tunnel/